# Removing cuda-repo Network Installer and installing the local version

Tags: nvidia, package-management, cuda

I have followed the instructions in a [tutorial](http://www.r-tutor.com/gpu-computing/cuda-installation/cuda6.5-ubuntu) to install cuda on Ubuntu 14.04. Problem is that I didn't notice that I installed the Network Version of the cuda-repo*.deb . How can I change this and install the local version instead of the network one?

Comment: What do you mean with "local version"?

Comment: At the site of CUDA-downloads (- https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads), on the Linux section, there is option to download a Network installer or Local package installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the **Network Installer** version

   - with with conf files

     ```
     sudo dpkg --purge cuda-repo-ubuntu1404
     ```
   - without conf files

     ```
     sudo dpkg --remove cuda-repo-ubuntu1404
     ```
2. Install the **Local Package Installer** version with

   ```
   sudo dpkg --install cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-0-local_7.0-28_amd64.deb
   ```